# Pandas: filter timestamps from dataframe A based on timestamp range in dataframe B for multiple categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

The first data frame (df1) has parent category, child category, and timestamp columns. The second data frame (df2) has the minimum and the maximum values of the timestamps for each parent and child category.

I want to filter timestamps in df1 in such a way that, for each parent-child category, only the timestamps within the minimum and the maximum bounds (inclusive) as specified by df2 are retained.

For reprex, here is a subset of the two data frames extracted from a larger sample:

```
import pandas as pd

data_df1 = [[2, 9, "2023-01-10 15:03:24.100"],
            [2, 9, "2023-01-10 15:03:30.500"],
            [2, 9, "2023-01-10 15:05:20.300"],
            [2, 9, "2023-01-10 15:05:59.600"],
            [2, 10, "2023-01-10 15:03:24.100"],
            [2, 10, "2023-01-10 15:03:30.500"],
            [2, 11, "2023-01-10 15:03:40.300"],
            [2, 11, "2023-01-10 15:04:42.600"],
            [2, 11, "2023-01-10 15:05:54.600"],
            [3, 9, "2023-01-10 15:05:54.100"],
            [3, 9, "2023-01-10 15:06:30.500"],
            [3, 9, "2023-01-10 15:07:20.300"],
            [3, 9, "2023-01-10 15:08:59.600"],
            [3, 10, "2023-01-10 15:05:55.200"],
            [3, 10, "2023-01-10 15:06:01.500"],
            [3, 10, "2023-01-10 15:06:10.300"],
            [3, 11, "2023-01-10 15:05:59.600"],
            [3, 11, "2023-01-10 15:06:05.600"],
            [3, 11, "2023-01-10 15:06:06.900"]]

data_df2 = [[2, 9, "2023-01-10 15:03:25.600", "2023-01-10 15:05:53.600"],
            [2, 10, "2023-01-10 15:03:24.200", "2023-01-10 15:03:34.500"],
            [2, 11, "2023-01-10 15:03:41.900", "2023-01-10 15:05:53.900"],
            [3, 9, "2023-01-10 15:05:55.400", "2023-01-10 15:08:23.200"],
            [3, 10, "2023-01-10 15:05:55.200", "2023-01-10 15:06:03.100"],
            [3, 11, "2023-01-10 15:05:56.000", "2023-01-10 15:06:06.000"]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_df1, columns = ['Parent_Cat', 'Child_Cat', 'TimeStamp'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df2, columns = ['Parent_Cat', 'Child_Cat', 'Tmin', 'Tmax'])
```

So, for the above dataset, df1, out of 0-18 row indices, should retain the following: 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, and 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df1['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['TimeStamp'])
df2['Tmin'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Tmin'])
df2['Tmax'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Tmax'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Parent_Cat','Child_Cat'], how='left')

df = df.loc[df['TimeStamp'].between(df['Tmin'], df['Tmax'], inclusive=True), 
            df1.columns]
print (df)
    Parent_Cat  Child_Cat               TimeStamp
1            2          9 2023-01-10 15:03:30.500
2            2          9 2023-01-10 15:05:20.300
5            2         10 2023-01-10 15:03:30.500
7            2         11 2023-01-10 15:04:42.600
10           3          9 2023-01-10 15:06:30.500
11           3          9 2023-01-10 15:07:20.300
13           3         10 2023-01-10 15:05:55.200
14           3         10 2023-01-10 15:06:01.500
16           3         11 2023-01-10 15:05:59.600
17           3         11 2023-01-10 15:06:05.600
```